# How to fix project classes having unwanted R subclass

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

The project was just working yesterday, but when I started Android Studio today. It was all messed up.

The main problem is my classes are having an unwanted 'R' subclass.

How to fix this?

I've tried 'Invalidate Caches/Restart' 'Rebuild project' 'clean project' 'Removing .idea folder' etc.

[image]

Comment: Unwanted R subclass? What do you mean?

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue!

I deleted "C:\Users\Suda.AndroidStudio3.4\system\caches" and boom my error fixed.